# Cant access the serialized data from AJAX inside an PHP file

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Trying to get the send data inside an Wordpress plugin but I cant get the data to work. So how do I get the data from the serialized part inside a php file?

// the code

```
<form method="post" id="form-settings" action="ajaxpro.php" >  

  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'settings', 'settings_nonce', false );?> 

  <input    name="field-one" type="text"/>
  <input    name="field-two" type="text"/>
  <textarea name="field_three">Hello world</textarea>

  // notice the double fields

  <input name="field-x[]" type="text"/>
  <input name="field-x[]" type="text"/>
  <input name="field-x[]" type="text"/>
  <input name="field-x[]" type="text"/>
  <input name="field-x[]" type="text"/>

  <button id="submitme" name="save-form">Save</button>

</form>



$('body').on('submit', '#form-settings', function(e){

  var seri =$(this).serializeArray()
   $.post(ajaxurl, {
       action:  'save_ajax_func',
       posted: seri
   }, function(response) {
       console.log( response );     
   });


   return false;

});


//notice that I do use double field names(field-x)

echo $_POST[ 'posted' ][ 'field-one' ] // not working
```

Comment: yeah I forgot to put that line inside the demo above ;-)

Comment: Lets see the form's html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `[]` notation in the html it would be `posted[field-x]`

```
  <input name="posted[field-x]" type="text"/>
```

the ajax will have to change to below

```
var seri = $(this).serializeArray();
seri.push({name:'action',value:'save_ajax_func'});
$.post(ajaxurl, seri, function(response) {
       console.log( response );     
});
```